# OperationalError at Django + Apache + wsgi Read-only file system

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, mod-wsgi

I deployed my code with django 1.6.11 and wsgi. My website was up and running and suddenly below error popped up.

I did sync and initialize my db and changed the permissions but still not able to resolve this error. Any inputs?

```
OperationalError at /
FATAL:  could not open file "base/16386/12805": Read-only file system

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://starcast.com/

Django Version: 1.6.11

Exception Type: OperationalError

Exception Value:    
FATAL:  could not open file "base/16386/12805": Read-only file system

Exception Location: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/starcast_prod/venv/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect, line 130

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python

Python Version: 2.7.13

Python Path:    
['/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/starcast_prod/starcast',
 '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/starcast_prod/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',

'/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',

'/usr/local/lib/python2.7',

 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',

 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',

 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',

 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',

 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 23 May 2017 17:58:50 -0500
```

Comment: The current working directory of the process is typically '/'. Don't expect it to be where your application source code is. Don't use relative path names, always calculate an absolute path based on some configuration setting. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory

Comment: Thanks  Graham Dumpleton for your response. At this moment, I don't have permissions to do changes in wsgi file. Does restarting apache server will help?

Comment: What is wanting to open the file by the path ``"base/16386/12805"``? You need to find out where that is occurring.

Comment: It seems post reboot my file system has turned into read-only in order to protect the data, now I need to find out how to restore it with limited permissions I have.